# phpredis can not connect to 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: php, redis

Below is error info:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message 'Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:6379' in /var/www/html/index.php:3 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/index.php(3): Redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3
```

But actually when using `redis-cli` to connect 127.0.0.1:6379, it still works.
`phpredis` was cloned form GitHub with master branches, local phpversion is 5.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

finally I've found the problem :

***setenforce 0***

I don't know why , but it works!

may helpful to u guys...